# Java spring mvc resource handler path

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, netbeans

I am relatively new to Java EE Spring Framework.
I am running a spring mvc spring maven project in Netbeans and I have the following structure for the "Web Pages" directory in the project files:

-Web Pages
--WEB-INF
---views
----welcome.jsp
-resources
--DPI.PNG

and this is the configuration class:

public class HelloWorldConfiguration {

```
@Bean(name = "HelloWorld")
public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
    InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
    viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
    viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");

    return viewResolver;
}

public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {

    // Css resource.
    registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**") //
            .addResourceLocations("/resources/");

}
```

}

and in the welcome.jsp I access the image using the following html:

```
<img src='/resources/DPI.PNG'>
```

and when I access the page it gives 404 not found for the image,

What is the problem??

Comment: Note that `/resources/DPI.PNG` will point to `localhost/resources/DPI.PNG`. Unless you did some different setting, your application will have a context path. You need to consider the context path if you want to display the image. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5066061/context-path-in-uris-of-static-resources-do-i-really-need-to-specify-it) you can find an example with JSTL.

Comment: To debug this, you can also try monitoring the network tab in chrome console and see what URL is being invoked for the URL.

Answer (score -1):

Try using jstl tag  which includes the context path of the application.

```
<img src="<c:url value="/resources/DPI.PNG"/c:url>">
```